# same x86 assembly instruction differs between NASM and GAS

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, gnu-assembler, opcode

the assembly code is

```
mov eax, 0x3a14a5
jmp eax
```

GAS produces an opcode of

```
0xB8, 0xA5, 0x14, 0x3A, 0x00 
0xFF, 0xE0
```

while NASM produces and opcode of

```
0x66, 0xB8, 0xA5, 0x14, 0x3A, 0x00 
0x66, 0xFF, 0xE0
```

So you see NASM preappends a 0x66 before the code.  Within my program (which I won't go into details about), the GAS opcode works correctly, and the NASM code causes a crash indicating that these two opcodes are not equal.  Why does NASM preappend the 0x66 and how can I get rid of it?

update:  The `bits 32` directive worked.  Thanks for the quick reply, links, and explanations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `bits 32` directive at the beginning of your assembly file, and NASM should generate the same machine code as GAS for this instruction.

More info in [the NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html):

> In BITS 32 mode ... 32-bit instructions require no prefixes, whereas instructions using 16-bit data need an 0x66 and those working on 16-bit addresses need an 0x67.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html:

> The codes o16 and o32 indicate that the given form of the instruction
>   should be assembled with operand size 16 or 32 bits. In other words,
>   o16 indicates a 66 prefix in BITS 32 state, but generates no code in
>   BITS 16 state; **and o32 indicates a 66 prefix in BITS 16 state but
>   generates nothing in BITS 32**

MOV instruction encoding:

> MOV reg32,imm32               ; **o32** B8+r id

So apparently you are in bits 16 mode.
Try prepending your file with a bits flag, eg.

```
bits 32
```